# IMGUR photo upload POST Request

Tags: c#, http, post, request, imgur

what im trying to do is to make photo upload to imgur site using their API here http://api.imgur.com/endpoints/image#image-upload. As i read in documentation, image data has to be in "image" parameter. So what im doing is setting POST request data as "image=base64codedfile&title=blabla&type=base64" and it does upload it but file is corrupted. If my request will contain only "base64codedfile" without image, title, type name parameters its working like a charm. Am i doing something wrong?

If i set it as:

```
string postData = "image="+Convert.ToBase64String(image)+"&type=base64&title=test;
```

image is corrupted

If it's only raw data:

```
string postData = Convert.ToBase64String(image);
```

It's working

Whole code is something like this:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.imgur.com/3/upload.xml");
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Client-ID >>myclientid<<");
request.Method = "POST";

string filePath = "d:\\test.jpg";
FileStream file = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);
byte[] image = new byte[file.Length];
file.Read(image, 0, (int)file.Length);
ASCIIEncoding enc = new ASCIIEncoding();
string postData = Convert.ToBase64String(image);
byte[] bytes = enc.GetBytes(postData);

request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

Stream writer = request.GetRequestStream();
writer.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Comment: You should check the return value of `file.Read(image, 0, (int)file.Length);` because it may not actually be `file.Length`.

Comment: it is good, like i said. If no "image=", "type=" parameters are in POST request, photo is uploading correctly.

Comment: I had this problem too of image not uploading if I was passing other parameters on their latest API version (currently the version is 3), did you figure out if there was a way of uploading with a title and/or description?

Comment: I'm sorry but no, I left it as it was

Answer (score 0):

I am also trying to do the same and also facing the problem...

I got one solution...

After uploading your image get the id of the image using **response.getresponsestream(**)....
then using this id update that image..and dont forget to use imgur api to update image..to know more about updating imgur image visit this [link](http://api.imgur.com/endpoints/image#image-upload%5C).

Comment: You haven't included the link, could you edit this with more information please?

Answer (score 0):

My solution :

```
      using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var objText = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

in object text you will found the json response